# How to measure distance continously and track my path in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a requirement to measure the distance continously and track the path in the end. How to do it form the app? Is there an api exposed by google maps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use The Google Distance Matrix API combining lat. and long. data from location service of the device.

Comment: So I should register with the location listner and fetch the lat and long for every 30seconds and then calculate the distance with google distance matrix?

Comment: yea! but i think you don't have to make it 30 seconds. You can record the last location and then when you get the current location, you can substract  them and calculate the distance. If you are able; 5, 10 or 15 seconds would be better.

Comment: I am storing all the lat longs in an array and for every 3 minutes I am calculatiing the distance matrix api. Is this the right way to do? How to handle scenarios when there is a loss of internet.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a pseudo code below

```
private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation)
{
    if (previousLocation != null)
    {
        new googledistancematixapitask(previouslocation.getlatlong(),new location.getlatlong()).execute((Void) null);
    }
    previousLocation = newLocation;
}
public class googledistancematixapitask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

private final String mSourcelatlong;
private final String mDestinationlatlong;


Postyouridetask(String sourcelatlong, String destinationlatlong) {
    mSourcelatlong = sourcelatlong;
    mDestinationlatlong = destinationlatlong;

}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... param) {
    // Building Parameters
    /*List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    // post album id, song id as GET parameters
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", mName));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mEmail));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profile", mProfile));*/
    try {
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("sourcelatlong", mSourcelatlong);
        params.put("destinationlatlong", mDestinationlatlong);

        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("google distance matrix api", "POST",
                params);



        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        if(jObj != null){
            String data = jObj.getString("success");

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return distance;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String distance) {
   totaldistance += distance;
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {

}
```

1) if we get a location update and it performs a async task and is still waiting for google to return the distance. If a second update comes and performs the asynctask before the first one completes. Wont we get a wrong result at the end when we calculate the total distance?